# Git Setup for web development without git server, using local network

Tags: git

I have been trying to setup git for our web development team unsuccessfully.  Some stackoverflow users were nice enough to get me started by helping me figure out how I should set it up in the environment we have; however, after trying to actually implement it I've run into some problems.  We are trying to set this up for developing Wordpress themes and plugins.

[Setting up Git on Network and the copying to website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707323/setting-up-git-on-network-and-the-copying-to-website)

Yesterday, I copied the themes and plugins folders from our production server to the network file server.  I then opened the command line that comes with Git for Windows, navigated to the folder on the file server and did this for each theme and plugin to create a repository on the network:

```
$ git init
$ git add *
$ git commit -m 'initial project version'
```

Then, on my workstation I navigated to the themes (and later plugins) folder and did this for each theme and plugin:

```
$ git clone /path/to/network/repository
```

It cloned in the files and everything seemed like it was going smoothly.  Then, I tested a commit and tried pushing it back to the network file server.  This gave me an error saying that the file on the network was checked out.  After searching on web for what I was doing wrong, I discovered that maybe (I think) I should have created a bare repository on the network file server.  So, now I'm looking for someone who can tell me if I'm heading in the right direction or not. After spending all day yesterday doing that only to find out that I was doing it wrong I thought maybe I should verify this, here's a graphic representation of what I now think I should have done:

[image: new git plan]

In this plan, a repository is created on the network file server that has a working copy of the files.  From that, a bare repository will be created in a separate directory on the network file server.  The workstations will fetch and merge from the bare repository, then push back to it.  Then, the non-bare network repository will pull from the bare repository.  Next, the files will be manually copied from the non-bare network repository to the staging server to be tested.  After testing, our server admin will copy the changes from staging to production.

Does this make any sense at all?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes sense. It should work fine. What's your branching strategy? Here's mine: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

I'm not sure if this is a proper question. Can you refine what you need answered?

Comment: Thanks!  i don't have a branching strategy yet :P

I guess my question beyond if this seems like a decent plan (you're right, I wasn't very clear on that) is whether or not the repository with the files on the network should be there, or if I should just have the bare repository on the network and then copy to staging from the workstations.

Comment: That's a detail and either would be fine. You can get a "checkout" of a branch from a bare repo but it includes more esoteric options on the git part of any git commands. What you have here will be the path of least resistance. You can refine later with no incurred costs meanwhile.